# expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token in vector

Tags: c++

I am getting following and not able to figure out. Any Point.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
typedef std::vector<std::string> fom_header;
typedef std::vector<fom_header> fom_data;

void print_data(fom_data &f)
{
    vector<fom_header>::iterator _header;
    vector<string>::iterator _data;
    for(_header = f.begin(); _header != f.end(); _header++)
    {
        for(_data = _header->begin(); _data != _header->end(); _data++)
        {
            cout<<"data ..."<<*_data;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    fom_header.push_back("A");
    fom_header.push_back("10");
    fom_header.push_back("20");
    fom_header.push_back("30");
    fom_data.push_back(fom_header);

    fom_header.push_back("B");
    fom_header.push_back("30");
    fom_header.push_back("40");
    fom_header.push_back("50");
    fom_data.push_back(fom_header);

    print_data(fom_data);

}
```

**Error**

```
create_2d.cpp:24:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:25:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:26:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:27:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:28:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:30:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:31:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:32:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:33:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:34:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
create_2d.cpp:36:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: You should try to restrict your code samples to relevant code. This problem could have been reproduced in about five lines of code.

Comment: Agree...I was sure I would not have any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fom_header` is a type. You need an instance of that type:

```
fom_header hdr;
hdr.push_back("hello");
```

Likewise for `fom_data`.

Answer (score 1):

`fom_header` here is just a type, not a `vector<string>` variable. You need to define a variable of this type before calling `push_back()` (and similar thing you need to do for `fom_data`):

```
fom_header fom;
fom.push_back("A");
```