# "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token" in class.cpp file

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have some classes and variables defined as so

ClassA.cpp

```
//#include "ClassB.h" & "ClassA.h"

ClassA currObj;

currObj.SetInfo(...);  // works
classAVect.push_back(currObj); // "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token"
```

ClassA.h

```
//#include "ClassB.h"

private:
    typedef std::vector<ClassB> ClassAVect;
```

I thought that error was for accessing a class that didn't have an instance of the type. So I must not be accessing my private vector correctly? I get that error whenever I try to access that vector using ADT (`.at()`, `.size()`, ..) in that format. I thought since the vector is already of the ClassA type, then I could access it directly with `push_back()`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: where's `classAVect` definition?

Comment: Show some code where `classAVect` is defined. All I see is a `ClassAVect` typedef (type alias) for a vector of `ClassB` objects.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Can you explain defined? Like a ```classAVect vectVar```? My plan was to add values using push_back()

Comment: `ClassA.h` needs `#include "ClassB.h"` (and make sure that classb.h does not include classa.h)

Comment: @user3365922 Can you explain defined? I went in more detail in another reply

Comment: _"So I must not be accessing my private vector correctly?"_ -- there is no private vector that we can see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361874/expected-unqualified-id-before-token-in-vector)

Comment: @JaMiT The private vector is in ClassA.h

Comment: @JaMiT I looked at that post earlier and I didn't understand. Now I do. Thank you! My approach was a little different, so I removed the typedef from the vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed the typedef and I was able to use the vector as normal. I don't know if I will need to change that back later on but for now, that works